Batch normalization in neural network for regression task
I have this neural network that I want to fit for regression. When I don't use batch normalization between layers it performs good, but when I add batch normalization it performs really bad.
For example MAE without batch normalization is 17000, while with batch normalization is huge 180000. Why is that?
X = train_data.drop(['SalePrice'], axis=1)
y = train_data['SalePrice']

# Get columns per type
numeric_cols = [col for col in X.columns if X[col].dtype in ['float64', 'int64']]
categoric_cols = [col for col in X.columns if X[col].dtype == 'object']

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

#  Pipeline for transformations
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('impute_numeric', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scale', StandardScaler())
])

categoric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('impute_categoric', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('encode', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
])

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_cols),
    ('cat', categoric_transformer, categoric_cols)
])

# Fit transformer
transformed_X_train = preprocessing.fit_transform(X_train)
transformed_X_val = preprocessing.transform(X_val)

# Model 14392
input_shape = transformed_X_train.shape[1]
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(units=256, activation='swish', input_shape=[input_shape]),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(units=256, activation='swish'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(units=128, activation='swish'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(units=128, activation='swish'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(units=64, activation='swish'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(units=64, activation='swish'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(units=1),
])

# Set optimizer and loss function
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mae'
)

early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    min_delta=0.01, # minimum amount of change to count as improvement
    patience=20, # number of epochs that need to have failed min_delta for early stopping to stop
    restore_best_weights=True,
)

# Fit neural network
history = model.fit(
    transformed_X_train, y_train,
    epochs=200,
    batch_size=128,
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
    validation_data=(transformed_X_val, y_val)
    # validation_split=0.2, # automatically creates test and validation set
)


history_df = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
history_df.loc[0:, ['loss', 'val_loss']].plot()

# Best 13962.4795
print("Evaluation of a model", model.evaluate(transformed_X_val, y_val, batch_size=128))
plt.show()


I don't know if BN will help you in this case, but the way you are using it is not the recommended one. You should place your Dense Layer and set the argument use_bias=False, do not use activation. Then, place the BatchNormalization layer. Then, explicitly add your Activation layer.

may I ask why it wouldn't help and why to put BN between would like to know more @stateMachine
